# Post MetaTable Overload

Tags: post-meta, memory, fatal-error

Anyone run a wp site with a large amount of post meta data?  My site uses ACF with several custom post types and at least 20 custom meta fields with each of my custom post types.  I have over 1000 posts in each of my custom post types and let's just say my post meta table is splurging.  It was definitely not designed for so many custom meta fields and cpts.  I was wondering if anyone had recommendations or experience in splitting the wp post meta table into separate tables possibly base on custom post type?  Or any other recommendations on how to deal with very large amounts of custom meta data?

BTW I am receiving a whitescreen of death in the admin section of wp for my custom posts, because the memory limit is being exhausted.  I have already increased the memory limit to -1 and eliminated any extra data being queried, still white screen.

Thanks

Comment: Enable `WP_DEBUG` in `wp-config.php` - Also read [Common WordPress Errors](http://codex.wordpress.org/Common_WordPress_Errors). I have several thousand posts with numerous Custom Post Types and a LOT of post meta. My websites run just fine. It could be a conflict of plugins or just a poorly coded plugin which is eating up your memory. Another thing to note would be the number of posts you are displaying per page in the admin section. Especially if your post listing tables are displaying data from post meta. Try reducing the number of posts displayed in your post listing tables.

Comment: @Michael Eckland what do you use to handle your post meta, do you code your own or have a plugin like ACF or HumanMande CMB?

Comment: I handle Post Meta with my own custom code.